# how to setup dsl on two wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, adsl, wifi-configuration

I have ADSL internet connection which is connected to my wifi A, I used a cable to connect my second wifi B to wifi A, so I plugged the cable in the first output port in the wifi A and then connected it to the input port of the wifi B.

the internet is functioning normally on wifi A but there is no internet access on the wifi B, so how I can setup it to access the internet from the two wifi?

Comment: You may need to log in to the wifi B (router?), and configure it to act as an access point. How to do this depends on the model of the device that you call WiFi B.

Comment: as @Peter points out you need to turn wifi B into an Access Point, although another term that might be used in wifi B's GUI is "Bridge mode"

Comment: wifi B is TL-WR340G